# How can I identify what class of graph algorithm to apply to this problem and possibly how to solve it?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have this graph problem I would like to solve. I am not sure what algorithm to apply to it.
Maybe depth first search, topological sort or something else. Even if I know which one was
necessary I am not sure I would be able to apply it. Maybe someone can point me in the right
direction. If you want to completely solve it, you are also welcome, but you should also explain
it, because that's also important and not just get the code. Thank you in advance.

Problem statement:

In the city of N, under unclear circumstances, the territory of one of the factories turned into
an anomalous zone. All entrances to the territory were blocked, and it was named an industrial zone.
There are N buildings in the industrial zone, some of them connected by roads. On any road, you
can move in both directions.

A novice stalker was given the task to get to the warehouse in the industrial zone. He found
several maps of the industrial zone's territory in the electronic archive.
Since the maps were created by different people, each of them contains information
only about certain roads in the industrial zone. The same road can appear on several maps.
On the way, the stalker can upload one map from the archive to the mobile phone.
When loading a new map, the previous one is not saved in the phone's memory.
The stalker can only move along roads marked on the currently loaded map.
Each card download costs 1 dollar. To
minimize costs, the stalker needs to choose a route that allows them to load maps as few times as possible.
A stalker can download the same map several times, and you will have to pay
for each download. Initially, there is no map in the mobile phone's memory.

You need to write a program that calculates the minimum amount of expenses required
for a stalker to get from the entrance to the industrial zone to the warehouse.

Input data format:

The first line of the input file contains two natural numbers N and K (2 ≤ N ≤ 2000; 1 ≤ K ≤
2000) — the number of buildings in the industrial zone and the number of maps, respectively.
The entrance to the industrial zone is located in
building number 1, and the warehouse is located in building number N.

The following lines contain information about available maps.
First line of the I-th description maps contains the number ri— the number of roads marked on the i-th map.
Then come ri-strings containing two natural numbers a and b each (1 ≤ a, b ≤ N; a ≠ b)
indicating that there is a road connecting buildings a and b on the i-th map.
The total number of roads marked on all maps does not
exceed 300,000 (r1+ r2+ … + rK ≤ 300 000).

Output data format:

In the output file, you need to output one number — the minimum amount of expenses of the stalker.
If you can't get to the warehouse, print the number -1.

Examples or test cases:

Example 1:

```
Input:

5 3 
1
3 4
3
1 2
1 3
2 4
1
4 5

output:

2
```

Example 2:

```
Input:

5 3
2
3 2
4 5
1
2 1
2
1 3
5 4

output:

-1
```

Example 3:

```
input:

12 4
4
1 6
2 4
7 9
10 12
3
1 4
7 11
3 6
3
2 5
4 11
8 9
5
3 10
10 7
7 2
12 3
5 12

output:

3
```

Comment: It seems like you can use Dijkstra's algorithm on the map whose nodes are pairs (building, current map) and edges are (b, m) to (b', m) (with cost 0) where b and b' are joined on the current map m, and edges (b, m), (b, m') (with cost 1). The graph has at most 4 million nodes, and at most 4.3 million edges. You can reduce the size of the graph by collapsing connected components of buildings for each map, but I guess that's not necessary to solve the problem in reasonable time.

Comment: I've removed your explanations of the three examples. I'm not sure if you don't understand the input format or you've just phrased your explanations badly. In any event, I don't think they add anything to the question since the description is clear on its own.

Comment: I don't think this is a great question for stackoverflow, because it's essentially "tell me how to solve this problem" (even if you've phrased it as "tell me how I can identify a solution to problems like this") and the problem is a study problem rather than a real-world problem. I don't know if it's homework or you're practicing algorithms questions, but the advice for such questions is relevant either way: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @PaulHankin thank you for the formatting. I am new to stack overflow and trying to see how everything works. I will try to see if the dijkstra approach leads to any fruitful outcome. Of course we will also try to follow all the guidelines listed in the article you linked above. Thank you